# Passing Bitmap as a memeber between activities

Tags: android, bitmap

ALL,

I have a following class:

```
public class Device implements Parcelable
{
private Bitmap photo;
private String bitmapURL;
private char sex;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String phone;
private double latitude;
private double longtitude;
private ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
private boolean isFriend;
private boolean doNotDisturb = false;

Device()
{   
    setDoNotDisturb(false);
}

Device(String a, char b, String c, String d, String e, double f, double g, boolean h)
{
    bitmapURL = a;
    sex = b;
    fname = c;
    lname = d;
    phone = e;
    latitude = f;
    longtitude = g;
    isFriend = h;
    setDoNotDisturb(false);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Device(Parcel in)
{
    photo = (Bitmap) in.readParcelable( Bitmap.class.getClassLoader() );
    sex = (char) in.readInt();
    fname = in.readString();
    lname = in.readString();
    phone = in.readString();
    latitude = in.readDouble();
    longtitude = in.readDouble();
    messages = in.readArrayList( Device.class.getClassLoader() );
    bitmapURL = in.readString();
    isFriend = in.readInt() == 1 ? true : false;
    doNotDisturb = in.readInt() == 1 ? true : false;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
{
    dest.writeValue( photo );
    dest.writeInt( sex );
    dest.writeString( fname );
    dest.writeString( lname );
    dest.writeString( phone );
    dest.writeDouble( latitude );
    dest.writeDouble( longtitude );
    dest.writeList( messages );
    dest.writeString( bitmapURL );
    dest.writeInt( isFriend ? 1 : 0 );
    dest.writeInt( doNotDisturb ? 1 : 0 );
}

}
```

and then I have the following code:

In Activity1.java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), PhotoTaker.class );
intent.putExtra( "device", device );
startActivity( intent );
```

And in PhotoTaker.java I have the following code:

```
device.setPhoto( bmp  );
Intent intent = new Intent( context, SexSelector.class );
intent.putExtra( "device", device );
startActivity( intent );
```

Now, the code in Activity1 works, while the code in PhotoTaker does not. There is no exception, there is nothing in the CatLog. It just silently crashing and the code comes back to the Activity1 instead of starting SexSelector activity.

Does anybody have an idea what is going on? And how do I fix the code so that the code will follow on the SexSelector activity?

I could create a Bitmap object in the Device constructor, but then I don't see how do I set the appropriate Bitmap on the actual object. Then I could've used photo.writeToParcel() to write the bitmap to parcel, but in this case I will simply get memory leak.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the size of the image? Generally passing anything large (about 1mb or so) will fail as the extra size is limited.

Comment: @Falkon, I'm scaling the image according to the Android guidelines. It is scaling according to the default ImageView sizing.